# Insert multiple values into oracle DB

Tags: mysql, oracle, converters

I have ~700 MB of insert statements for my oracle DB but the statements were used to insert data in a MySQL DB. The syntax therefore is

```
    INSERT INTO TABLE 
        (EXCH_WH_KEY, EXCH_EFF_DATE) 
        VALUES
    (1, '28-AUG-2008'),
    (2, '28-AUG-2008'),
    (3, '28-AUG-2008');
```

and so on. But since it's ~700 MB of statements I can't update all of their syntax'. What's the fastest way to get the data into my oracle DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the data into a MySQL database and then use [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) with the `--compatible=oracle` flag to export it in an Oracle compatible format.  Then insert into the Oracle database as per normal.

If this doesn't work (as indicated in the comment below), you can resort to string concatenation to read from the MySQL database and generate the Oracle compatible insert statements, eg:

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO mytable(EXCH_WH_KEY, EXCH_EFF_DATE) VALUES (', EXCH_WH_KEY, ', \'', EXCH_EFF_DATE, '\')') FROM mytable;
```

Note that the String column has to be wrapped in escaped quotes.

Comment: Ok thanks I already feared it would come to this... Do you have any proposal for a MySQL DB whitout much configuration steps ?

Comment: The standard MySQL is easy to install locally.

Comment: Another option would be to do a find and replace across the file to convert it to Oracle format. You'll probably need a tool like sed to do this, not just a text editor.

Comment: unfortunately the --compatible=oracle flag doesn't solve the problem. It executes no conversion. They also state that on the website "This option does not guarantee compatibility with other servers. It only enables those SQL mode values that are currently available for making dump output more compatible"

Comment: Updated the answer with an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

During executing ***mysqldump*** add `--extended-insert=FALSE` along with `--compatible=oracle` to make separate insert statements instead of one full insert.